# Do I need to buy individual ios developer subscriptions for the members of my team, if I have a company subscription?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple

My guess is I have to, and if I do, I'll buy them while the company license is under review.

Comment: Not subjective and does not belong here, but I won't flag it. Best choice would be StackOverflow, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  Once enrolled you can add individual Apple IDs to your development team using iTunes Connect.

The development tools are free and require no license to download, install and develop with.  Your distribution is the only part that requires registration and for that you can add the team members as necessary without additional licensing fees.

Comment: Except that the latest version of Xcode is not free. You need to be either a paid ADC member ($99) or buy it through the app store ($5).

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean that the added members will be able to debug iOS apps on their own hardware without limitations or they will need an individual developer subscription for that? Because as far as I know that feature is limited to paid subscriptions and I'm not sure if the company subscription will cover that for them.

Comment: @user22418 you are limited to 99 devices per year to directly deploy too (and unlimited app store distribution) per subscription (With the $99 company license), you just have to include their UDID (from the device) in your provisioning portal. For in house distribution only (no app store), the $299 Enterprise license allows you to distribute your apps to anyone in your enterprise.